# Is there a way to to return one variable each from two separate tables, but only when two variables from each table match?

Tags: sql, dune

I have two separate queries that both work correctly. I have two common columns in each table "Day" and "Wallet".  I have one table that returns (Day, Wallet, Withdrawals) and another that returns (Day, Wallet, Sales).  I'd like to have a single query that returns joins "Withdrawals" and "Sales" but only for wallets that have a sale and withdrawal on the same day.

The code below allows m to call bonds_table (withdrawals) and sales_table, but I don't know how to return a single table that shows "dexSHARE Redeemed" and "dexSHARE Sold" when a single wallet makes both on the same day.

```sql
WITH
  bonds_table AS(
    SELECT
      DATE_TRUNC('day', "call_block_time") AS "Day",
      "_depositor" AS Wallet,
      sum("output_0") / 1e18 AS "dexSHARE Redeemed"
    FROM
      dexfinance."wBNB_bond_for_dexshare_call_redeem"
    WHERE
      "call_success" IS TRUE --Verify transaction was successful
    group by
      1,
      2
  ),
  --This table is for sales of the tokens
  sales_table AS(
    SELECT
      derivedTable1."Day",
      derivedTable1."to" AS Wallet,
      sum(derivedTable1."amountIn" / 1e18) AS "dexSHARE Sold"
    FROM
      -- This combines the sales from both tables so they can be summed
      (
        SELECT
          DATE_TRUNC('day', "call_block_time") AS "Day",
          "amountIn",
          "to"
        FROM
          pancakeswap_v2."PancakeRouter_call_swapExactTokensForETH" -- This table is for tokens to wBNB
        WHERE
          "path" [1] = '\xf4914e6d97a75f014acfcf4072f11be5cffc4ca6' -- Sale of dexSHARE
          AND call_success is TRUE -- Verify transaction was successful
          AND "call_block_time" >= TO_TIMESTAMP('2022-05-24', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
        UNION
        SELECT
          DATE_TRUNC('day', "call_block_time") AS "Day",
          "amountIn",
          "to" AS Wallet
        FROM
          pancakeswap_v2."PancakeRouter_call_swapExactTokensForTokens" -- This table is for tokens to other tokens (not wBNB)
        WHERE
          "path" [1] = '\xf4914e6d97a75f014acfcf4072f11be5cffc4ca6' -- Sale of dexSHARE
          AND call_success is TRUE -- Verify transaction was successful
          AND "call_block_time" >= TO_TIMESTAMP('2022-05-24', 'yyyy-mm-dd') -- Sales after this date (launch of Bond)
      ) AS derivedTable1
    GROUP BY
      1,
      2
  )
```

I know I need to append a SELECT statement at the end, but I'm lost with how to structure it.  Can anyone help me head down the correct direction?

Answer (score 0):

That of course depends what you want to achieve

but you can start from.

This would join both CTE's on the same day and wallet, and list also the "values"

```
WITH
  bonds_table AS(
    SELECT
      DATE_TRUNC('day', "call_block_time") AS "Day",
      "_depositor" AS Wallet,
      sum("output_0") / 1e18 AS "dexSHARE Redeemed"
    FROM
      dexfinance."wBNB_bond_for_dexshare_call_redeem"
    WHERE
      "call_success" IS TRUE --Verify transaction was successful
    group by
      1,
      2
  ),
  --This table is for sales of the tokens
  sales_table AS(
    SELECT
      derivedTable1."Day",
      derivedTable1."to" AS Wallet,
      sum(derivedTable1."amountIn" / 1e18) AS "dexSHARE Sold"
    FROM
      -- This combines the sales from both tables so they can be summed
      (
        SELECT
          DATE_TRUNC('day', "call_block_time") AS "Day",
          "amountIn",
          "to"
        FROM
          pancakeswap_v2."PancakeRouter_call_swapExactTokensForETH" -- This table is for tokens to wBNB
        WHERE
          "path" [1] = '\xf4914e6d97a75f014acfcf4072f11be5cffc4ca6' -- Sale of dexSHARE
          AND call_success is TRUE -- Verify transaction was successful
          AND "call_block_time" >= TO_TIMESTAMP('2022-05-24', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
        UNION
        SELECT
          DATE_TRUNC('day', "call_block_time") AS "Day",
          "amountIn",
          "to" AS Wallet
        FROM
          pancakeswap_v2."PancakeRouter_call_swapExactTokensForTokens" -- This table is for tokens to other tokens (not wBNB)
        WHERE
          "path" [1] = '\xf4914e6d97a75f014acfcf4072f11be5cffc4ca6' -- Sale of dexSHARE
          AND call_success is TRUE -- Verify transaction was successful
          AND "call_block_time" >= TO_TIMESTAMP('2022-05-24', 'yyyy-mm-dd') -- Sales after this date (launch of Bond)
      ) AS derivedTable1
    GROUP BY
      1,
      2
  )
SELECT bo."Day",bo."Wallet" ,bo."dexSHARE Redeemed",dexSHARE Sold"
FROM bonds_table bo JOIN sales_table sa ON sa."Wallet2  = o."Wallet"  AND sa."Day" = bo."Day"
```

Comment: Thank you.  This worked once with a few tweaks.  I appreciate your help!  Here is the final statement that I used:

```SELECT bo."Day",bo.Wallet ,bo."dexSHARE Redeemed", sa."dexSHARE Sold"
FROM bonds_table bo JOIN sales_table sa ON sa.Wallet  = bo.Wallet  AND sa."Day" = bo."Day"```

Comment: I can't +1 you because I don't have enough reputation, but +1 for this answer!